# Data pre-processing in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset and I am exploring the data, in a specific column of my data I have 11 different categories belongs to that specific column, however the data distribution of that column is as the following:

```py
Number of data points in class 1 : 87459 ( 60.074 %)
Number of data points in class 2 : 42278 ( 29.04 %)
Number of data points in class 3 : 14712 ( 10.105 %)
Number of data points in class 4 : 569 ( 0.391 %)
Number of data points in class 5 : 425 ( 0.292 %)
Number of data points in class 6 : 57 ( 0.039 %)
Number of data points in class 7 : 34 ( 0.023 %)
Number of data points in class 8 : 24 ( 0.016 %)
Number of data points in class 9 : 11 ( 0.008 %)
Number of data points in class 10 : 10 ( 0.007 %)
Number of data points in class 11 : 7 ( 0.005 %)
```

please notice that after class 3 till class 11 there is significant drop in the percentage of that data.

my question is I want to perform encoding to these categorical data, should I consider all the categories in that specific column no matter how low is the representation of the data, or simply consider the first 3 classes and exclude the rest from that column.

[image]

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try considering first 3 as 3 different categories and all the rest as one combined category and see how you model performs.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider the first three (highest) categories and neglect the rest. since they are very rare and have no contribution to your model alongside making your model more complex by "increasing the dimensionality".